Okhttp3 API Response Request Failure
I have an inventory scanner app that works correctly 95% of the time, but occasionally will get a failure response during a POST request and often times subsequent retries won't POST successfully unless the app is left alone for an extended period of time, which is not ideal. The WIFI is strong in most areas, but there are definitely some dead spots that may cause roaming or brief disconnection. However, the WIFI usually shows a strong signal during these POST attempts.
My current configuration for timeouts is:
        val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build()

I know the default is 10 seconds instead of 1. I lowered it because I didn't want a long response time, but this may not give enough time to connect. I also have retryOnConnectionFailure(true) because I wanted it to retry on it's own.
I am new to networking calls so please suggest how you usually would configure your timeouts in this situation or you have any other advice on my issue.
Thanks!
Tried modifying timeout durations, but it is hard to replicate the situations that failed attempts occur in.
